# How to add variable inside a Character Class using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to add a variable inside a Character Class when using javascript regular expression. What I tried did not work. What the correct syntax for accomplishing this.
For example,

```
if(/[variable]/.test(Log))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax

```
var re = new RegExp(variable);
```

and then use

```
 re.test(Log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var regex = new RegExp(variable);
if(regex.test(Log)){
    // your logic
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
a='.*'
var patt=new RegExp(a);
patt.test('asdsd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

```
if(/[variable]/.test(Log)) {

}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(new RegExp("["+variable+"]").test(Log)) {

}
```

#### Explanation:

Whenever you use a regex with the `//` notation, such as:

```
/[\d*]"+/
```

You can use the `RegExp` object and pass the regex as a escaped **string**. This way, the above regex is equivalent to:

```
new RegExp("[\\d*]\"+")
```

The **modifiers** can be passed as second argument. So that `/anything/gm` is the same as `new RegExp("anything", "gm")`.